# How is the volume graph on poloniex calculated?

Tags: exchanges, poloniex

So it says volume, but I wondered how the graph was calculated (% change around a moving average?)

Could anyone explain what formula they're using?

[image: Here is a screengrab of the graph I'm interested in]

Comment: Its MACD indicator or OSMA graph

Comment: It could be the MACD delta, that is the difference between the MACD and the signal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a little off-topic, as it's more related to general trading...

I believe this type of graph is called [Klinger Volume Oscillator](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/klingeroscillator.asp), and takes into account the current volume in relation to a general up- or downtrend. (So yes, it's around a moving average.)